# Proving $\frac{\sin\pi z}{\pi z}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(1-\frac{z^{2}}{n^{2}}\Big)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I apoligize if this has been answered already; the quick searches I've done have proven fruitless.

I'm given that

$\displaystyle\pi\cot(\pi z)=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2z}{z^{2}-n^{2}}$

and wish to derive

$\displaystyle\frac{\sin\pi z}{\pi z}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(1-\frac{z^{2}}{n^{2}}\Big)$

from this. I have taken the first equation, integrated both sides (using a u-substitution on the left-hand side with $u=\sin(\pi z)$ ) and come up with

$\displaystyle\ln(\sin(\pi z))=\ln(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln(z^2-n^2)=\ln\Big(z\prod_{n=1}^\infty (z^2-n^2)\Big)$ which yields $\displaystyle\sin(\pi z)=z\prod_{n=1}^\infty(z^2-n^2)$, but the product here doesn't converge. Where exactly am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a definite integral to actually have equality of both sides--otherwise you have a $f(x) = g(x) \rightarrow \int f(x)dx = \int g(x)dx + C$ where $C$ is unknown.  Also, my question would be what is the radius of convergence?  The cotangent isn't continuous (over the reals at least) and the original sum appears to diverge (which you essentially proved using the integral test).

Comment: How familiar you are with infinite products of complex functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more careful about your antiderivatives: firstly, the cotangent identity shows that
$$ \pi \cot{\pi z} - \frac{1}{z} $$
is finite (and hence integrable) in a neighbourhood of the origin (use the comparison test or the integral test or something). Hence,
$$ \int_0^z \left(\pi \cot{\pi w} - \frac{1}{w}\right) \, dw \tag{1} $$
exists: an antiderivative is
$$ \log{\left( \frac{\sin{\pi w}}{\pi w} \right)}, $$
so the integral (1) is
$$ \left[ \log{\left( \frac{\sin{\pi w}}{z} \right)} \right]_0^z = \log{\left( \frac{\sin{\pi z}}{\pi z} \right)} - \log{1} = \log{\left( \frac{\sin{\pi z}}{\pi z} \right)}. $$

Now, for the right-hand side, we observe that it is uniformly convergent on $[0,z]$ for $z$ small enough, so we can integrate term-by-term. We have
$$ \int_0^z \frac{2w}{w^2-n^2} \, dw, $$
and as you almost note, $\log{(n^2-w^2)}$ is an antiderivative (note the sign: $z<1$, so $z<n$). However, if we now evaluate the integral, we find
$$ \left[ \log{(n^2-w^2)} \right]_0^z = \log{(n^2-z^2)}-\log{(n^2)} = \log{\left( 1-\frac{z^2}{n^2} \right)} $$
Summing these up, exponentiating and multiplying by $\pi z$, we get
$$ \sin{\pi z} = \pi z \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac{z^2}{n^2} \right) $$
on $[-1+\varepsilon, 1-\varepsilon]$, for any $\varepsilon>0$, because we can only get uniform convergence here.

The remaining issue is periodicity: you have to check that the right-hand side has period $2$. Extending the identity over the integers is straightforward by taking $\varepsilon \to 0$ and checking continuity there.

Comment: Is their a proof via the Weierstrass's  Factorization Theorem ?

Comment: @Zophikel Yes, but it wouldn't use the cotangent. The Weierstrass factorisation theorem says that since $\sin{\pi z}$ has zeros at precisely the integers, $\sin{(\pi z)}/\pi z = e^{Az+B} \prod_{n \neq 0} \left( 1-\frac{z}{n} \right) e^{z/n} $. The left-hand side is even and has limit $1$ at $z=0$, so $A=B=0$, and then we use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2291020/221811) to rearrange the factors.